# List append not working inside case match?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to update two lists depending on the match but list keeps being empty.

```
test_list = []
other_list = []
Enum.map(some_maps, fn some_map ->
  case some_map do
    %{"test" => item} -> test_list ++ [item]
    %{"test2" => item} -> other_list ++ [item]
  end
end)
```

I also tried `test_list ++ item` and `test_list = test_list + [item]`

How could I approach this?

Comment: Is `some_maps` supposed to be a list of maps?

Comment: yes it is, some_maps = [%{"test" => item}, %{"test" => item}, %{"test2" => item} ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in Elixir are immutable so you can't modify it like this. I'd do it like this:

```
some_maps = [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test2" => 2}, %{"test" => 3}]

test_list = for %{"test" => item} <- some_maps, do: item
other_list = for %{"test2" => item} <- some_maps, do: item

IO.inspect test_list
IO.inspect other_list
```

```
[1, 3]
[2]
```

You can also use `Enum.reduce/3` here if you only want to iterate the map once but doing it this way is probably good enough and much more elegant.

Here's how to do it with `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
some_maps = [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test2" => 2}, %{"test" => 3}]

{test_list, other_list} = Enum.reduce(some_maps, {[], []}, fn
  %{"test" => item}, {t, o} -> {[item | t], o}
  %{"test2" => item}, {t, o} -> {t, [item | o]}
end)

test_list = Enum.reverse(test_list)
other_list = Enum.reverse(other_list)

IO.inspect test_list
IO.inspect other_list
```

The output is the same as before.

PS: Please post a complete example in the future, which in this case means a sample value for `some_maps`.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @Dogbert is perfect as usual, there is an explicitly dedicated function [`Enum.split_with/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_with/2) that does exactly what you want, namely *splits* the enumerable:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ some_maps = [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test2" => 2}, %{"test" => 3}]
#⇒ [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test2" => 2}, %{"test" => 3}]
iex|2 ▶ Enum.split_with(some_maps, fn 
...|2 ▶ %{"test" => _} -> true                          
...|2 ▶ %{"test2" => _} -> false
...|2 ▶ end)
#⇒ {[%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}], [%{"test2" => 2}]}
```

In this particular case, the comprehension definitely rules, but in some cases it might be helpful. To get the values, one should explicitly get `Map.values/1` on the resulting lists.